# I have an error on an optimization code in XGBoost

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am just learning Python and finding the various examples online varying in quality.

In summary I have copied code for an XGBoost optimizer if I run the code for the XGBClassifier it works fine (if I make the label a 1 or -1 output) however, if I amend the code to XGBRegressor (for trying to predict a stock price) if falls over; any ideas what is causing this?

I also have a strange error for the final pyplot code at the bottom when I run it nothing happens, no error, just nothing!

I am using Jupyter notebook on Windows.

```
model = XGBRegressor()
n_estimators = [5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 400, 500]
print(max_depth)
param_grid = dict(max_depth=max_depth, n_estimators=n_estimators)
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=7)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid, scoring="neg_log_loss", n_jobs=-1, cv=kfold, verbose=1)
grid_result = grid_search.fit(X, label_encoded_y)

scores = numpy.array(means).reshape(len(max_depth), len(n_estimators))
for i, value in enumerate(max_depth):
    pyplot.plot(n_estimators, scores[i], label='depth: ' + str(value))
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.xlabel('n_estimators')
pyplot.ylabel('Log Loss')
pyplot.savefig('n_estimators_vs_max_depth.png')
```

As I mentioned this works fine if I change to a XGBClassifier….apart from the pyplot code at the bottom which returns nothing, not even an error!

Comment: are you sure the model is fitting properly? You have set verbosity to 1 .. So what does it ouput when the fit is run?

Comment: This is the output if I use XGBRegressor. ValueError: n_splits=10 cannot be greater than the number of members in each class. If I use XGBClassifier it works fine and fits various models giving me an output. The verbosity is how I found the code online!